# How to install cakephp on localhost?

Tags: cakephp

I wanna to know how to install cakephp on localhost?
Please explain me.

Answer (score 5):

I usually make an apache and mysql installation on a linuxbox. I can use windows too, however I do not recommend it ;)
So, I usually make a new entry into the /etc/hosts file to make a sitename available to cakephp.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost caketest.local
```

next step to copy all cakephp files into a subdirectory inside /home/myusername/public_html/caketest

```
    app
    cake
    index.php
    plugins
    README
    vendors
    .htaccess
```

then I set up the site to apache (not neccessary),

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/home/myusername/public_html/caketest"
    ServerName caketest.local  
    # This should be omitted in the production environment
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

    <Directory "/home/myusername/public_html/caketest">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

restart apache. you also need to edit the .htaccess files and place a RewriteBase directive with hte path to the actual directory, e.g.

```
RewriteBase /~myusername/caketest
```

create a database, set the db connection in cake config files and that's all.
you can point your browser to http://caketest.local
if you do not want a test site url you can skip hosts, and apache vhost creation, but the url to use should be http:/localhost/~myusername/caketest

another important thing is to enable userdir modul in apache, and also check if using php is enabled in userdirs too.

Comment: +1 for a _complete_ answer including `hosts` file entry, named virtual hosts and `RewriteBase` for this particular config.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on windows, get [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/). Install it, then download CakePHP in `C:\wamp\www\`. Extract CakePHP in that folder so you have a folder kind of like this: `C:\wamp\www\cakephp\`. Now you can access the installation by going to localhost/cakephp/.

Answer (score 1):

An old article of mine but still quite relevant:

[Installing CakePHP](http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/installing_cakephp)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a *AMP setup (Apache+MySQL+PHP), just copy the files to your htdocs folder. On Ubuntu, it's `/var/www`, so you would create `/var/www/myApp` and copy the whole Cake structure into there, ending up with something like:

```
/var/www/myApp/app/
/var/www/myApp/cake/
/var/www/myApp/vendors/
/var/www/myApp/index.php
/var/www/myApp/.htaccess
```

Then you can access your app by the url: http://localhost/myApp