# How can I install cakephp in ubuntu next to my other php applications?

Tags: php, cakephp, ubuntu, lamp

I am  trying to install cakephp and begin learning how to build applications based on the framework but I can't get the browser to access the site on my localhost server. 
**Background information:**

- I am running Ubuntu 11.10  I have already installed lamp, and php
  myadmin.
- I am developing other projects in the /var/www/ folder that
  are running the joomla cms and they work fine.
- I am tryng to set up a    folder that will allow me to access the
  cake php application by going    to localhost/cakephp-blog in my
  browser.
- I followed all of the instructions on this
  site:http://blog.smalleycreative.com/programming/install-cakephp-on-ubuntu-10-10/
  and I ended up getting a 403 forbidden error. It blocked all of my

  other projects so I reversed that and now I'm here asking for help.

Right now I can access my other projects by typing in "http://localhost/project1", "http://localhost/project2", etc.

However, when I go to "http://localhost/cakephp-blog", I get nothing.

Thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: You might want to take a peak at the apache error log, usually under /var/log/apache2/

Comment: Try reading [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626012/how-to-install-cakephp-on-localhost).<br>
Also you can try this [explanation](http://kurinchilamp.kurinchilion.com/2009/07/configuring-cakephp-in-localhost.html).